# Difference between log4j.properties and logging.properties

Tags: docker, tomcat

What are the difference between log4j.properties and logging.properties?

Which one should I modify to log the application logs to catalina.2021.01.01?

Right now the docker image is logging only tomcat startup log to `catalina.2021.01.01` but the rest of the application log is printed onto console.

This is the current setttings

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
```

I'm trying to configure it application to log it `catalina.2021.01.01` and tomcat startup log `catalina.out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the configuration files of two different logging frameworks:

- `logging.properties` is the configuration file of `java.util.logging` default Java logging framework. Under Tomcat it is usually configured with a [special LogManager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default)), which allows you to use a different `logging.properties` for each application,
- `log4j.properties` is the configuration file for [Log4j 1.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).

As explained in [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html):

> A web application running on Apache Tomcat can:
>
> - Use any logging framework of its choice.
> - Use system logging API, `java.util.logging`.
> - Use the logging API provided by the Java Servlets specification, `javax.servlet.ServletContext.log(...)`

The usual choice is the first one.

Many applications use a logging facade (like [JCL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/), [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) or [Log4j 2 API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html)) and the facade chooses a backend (`java.util.logging`, Log4j 1.x, [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) or Log4j 2) according to the libraries you add to the class path.

So, in order to configure your application logs you need to know which framework it uses.